# Date and Time in Printing Header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

By deafault `window.print` shows in header just printing date.
I need to show printing date and time in the header. How can I do this?

if there is a way to define it run time?
For example here:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print"> ...
```

or in any other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution, might not be the best but will do the work:

Add this just below the `<body>` opening:

```
<div id="printDateTime"></div>
```

---

To get the date and time use javascript:

```
const today = new Date();
const date = today.getDate() + "/" + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getFullYear();
const time =
  today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("printDateTime").innerHTML =
  "Printed on: " + date + " at " + time;
```

---

Set it to `display: none;` in css:

```
#printDateTime {
  display: none;
}
```

And set is to `display: block;` in `print media queries`:

```
@media print {
  #printDateTime {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

---

If you want you can style it to as per your need, like:

```
#printDateTime {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

There is no need to add the styling CSS in media queries too.

---

***Codepen:** https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/LYRgXdx*

*Test it here (just go on the page and press `Ctrl`/`Cmd` + `p`): https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/full/LYRgXdx*

Comment: thanks a lot. but this is done not a header

Comment: `HTML 5` and `CSS3` have no support for changing or adding print header and footer. You can call this a hack. Just works ✌.